# Does react-native app refresh after setting permissions? (iOS only)

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

On some app page, I call

```
Linking.openURL('app-settings:1')
```

To open the Settings app to allow someone to give me access to the Camera if they have not already.

When I change a setting, the app refreshes, and pulls up the initial/start screen.

Is this standard behavior? Can I stop the refresh?

Is there a way to listen to the change-in-permissions without modifying a Redux state, and redirect to different pages if the permission was granted/not granted?

Comment: I was unable to find a way to prevent the refresh.

Comment: any update on this?